Alien having his head cut off with a chainsaw
I'm looking the the title of a movie with a cop (I think) who fights an alien. I saw the movie in the beginning of the 90's. The cop uses a chainsaw in the end and cuts the alien's head off, then drops it in the trash can (if I'm not mistaken). 
I may be wrong but I think the alien blood was glowing green or maybe it looked like black oil mixed with water (dark rainbowish).

Sounds like Deep Space with Charles Napier from 1988. From IMDb:

An American satellite with a new biological weapon gets out of control and crashes onto US territory. A slimy monster emerges and manages to escape, killing everyone who crosses his path. Police Lieutenant McLemore gets the job to stop the killing machine.

In the final battle with the alien, McLemore chops its head with a chainsaw. The head is then dumped into a barrel and jokingly advised that it has the right to remain silence. Most of that battle can be seen here:



